# Discord bot showing incorrect number of servers(showing 0)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I'm new at bot creating so sry if quesrion is stupid

Bot showing incorrect number of servers(showing 0) when starting 1 code but when starting 2 code it shows correctly, how to change 1 code that it will show correctly help pls

```
status = cycle( [f' on { len(client.guilds) } servers', '~help'] )
@tasks.loop( seconds = 5 )
async def changeStatus():
    await client.change_presence( activity = discord.Activity( type = discord.ActivityType.playing, name = next(status) ) )
 
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print( 'bot connected' )
    changeStatus.start()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print( 'bot connected')

    await client.change_presence( activity = discord.Game( f' on { len(client.guilds) } servers | ~help ') )
```

**Workin code but it isn't updating 5 sec if someone need help with updating check another my questions**

```
async def changeStatus():
    status = cycle( [f' on { len(client.guilds) } servers', '~help'] )
    await client.change_presence( activity = discord.Activity( type = discord.ActivityType.playing, name = next(status) ) )

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print( 'bot connected' )
    changeStatus.start()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The python interpreter will only run over

```
status = cycle( [f' on { len(client.guilds) } servers', '~help'] )
```

once, as it is defined as a global variable. This means that `len(client.guilds)` will always be the same number. And since the interpreter runs over this, before `on_ready()` was called, the value of this is 0. To fix this, put the declaration of `status` into your `changeStatus()` function.

```
@tasks.loop( seconds = 5 )
async def changeStatus():
    status = cycle( [f' on { len(client.guilds) } servers', '~help'] )
    await client.change_presence( activity = discord.Activity( type = discord.ActivityType.playing, name = next(status) ) )
```

Comment: Thanks, now it showing correct, but not changing every 5 sec

Answer (score 2):

You can't change it that fast. It is considered API abuse, against TOS i think. Try doing a more reasonable interval like 3 minutes.

Comment: The ratelimit for chaging presences is 5 requests per 1 minute per session iirc, so changing it every 12 seconds should be enough

Comment: but when i use my first code and replase for example 'status1' and 'status2' it works good, it depend when you use client.guilds?