# Discord bot not updating status

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I am new at python so sry if question is stupid but i hope u guys will help me.
Bot not updating status every 5 sec(i put more time like 5 min and it didn't work too). It shows number of servers and not changing to second status.

```
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
from itertools import cycle

@tasks.loop( seconds = 12 )
async def changeStatus():
    status = cycle( [f' on { len(client.guilds) } servers', '~help'] )
    await client.change_presence( activity = discord.Activity( type = discord.ActivityType.playing, name = next(status) ) )

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print( 'bot connected' )
    changeStatus.start()
```

Comment: If you are not able to work out this method, I use random.choice(list), it works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since

```
status = cycle( [f' on { len(client.guilds) } servers', '~help'] )
```

is called everytime you call your function, it will be reinterpreted, which means that the `next()` function always return the first element. To fix this, you will need a different approach. For example, create a global `iteration-variable` and declare you `cycle-list` as only a list.

```
iterationPosition = 0

@tasks.loop( seconds = 12 )
async def changeStatus():
    status = [f' on { len(client.guilds) } servers', '~help']
    await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.playing, name=status[iterationPosition]))
    iterationPosition = 0 if (iterationPosition == len(status) - 1) else (iterationPosition + 1)
```

You will need to keep track if you've reached the end of your list. This is done by the last line of code.

Comment: Erorr -
Unhandled exception in internal background task 'changeStatus'.
 await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.playing, name=status[iterationPosition]))
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'iterationPosition' referenced before assignment

Comment: That is strange behaviour to me. You can try using `iterationPosition` as a variable in your function call 
`iterationPosition = 0`
`changeStatus.start(functionPosition)`
Remove the global `iterationPosition` and put it inside the 
`async def changeStatus(functionPosition)`

Comment: maybe i understand smth incorrect but after i put `iterationPosition` as variable code doesn't work at all

Comment: i mean like this
`@tasks.loop( seconds = 12 )
async def changeStatus():
 iterationPosition = 0
    status = [f' on { len(client.guilds) } servers', '~help']
    await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.playing, name=status[iterationPosition]))
    iterationPosition = 0 if (iterationPosition is len(status) - 1) else (iterationPosition + 1)`

Comment: Not quite what I anticipated, but do you get an error?

Comment: no bot's .exe open and close immediately, which mean error in the code

Comment: i can't because erorrs shows in cmd but it immediately closing when i run the code

Comment: okay i run this part of code in online compiler and maybe this error is that we need  ```unindent does not match any outer indentation level

Comment: This means that something is indented wrong in your code -> this is hard to debug in comments, since there is no real formatting possible here. Maybe ask another question to resolve this!

Answer (score -1):

It is not changing the status as you got a **Presence Update rate-limit of 5/60secs per-session**. These rate-limits are dynamic so don't get too close to them

Comment: This isn't the problem here. It is a factor which needs to be considered, yes. But the actual problem is that `next()` is always returning the same element in this case.

Answer (score -1):

`status = cycle( [f' on { len(client.guilds) } servers', '~help'] )` This line should be outside of the `changeStatus` function as whenever it is called, it makes `[f' on { len(client.guilds) } servers` the first item.

Comment: Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67399463/discord-bot-showing-incorrect-number-of-serversshowing-0/67399556#67399556)

Comment: Ah i see, my bad.