# Discord bot doesn't work and not changing status

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

At first my discord bot doesn't work, in this code is erorr and i can't find it, and second is that it doesn't changing status, it was changing when you put just 2 text but when trying to put `client.guilds` it not

```
@tasks.loop( seconds = 12 )
async def changeStatus():
    iterationPosition = 0
    status = [f' on { len(client.guilds) } servers', '~help']
    await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.playing, name=status[iterationPosition]))
    iterationPosition = 0 if (iterationPosition is len(status) - 1) else (iterationPosition + 1)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print( 'bot connected' )
    changeStatus.start()
```

*Working code but with problem that he writes me answer to commands as many times as all servers he on

```
tasks.iterationPosition = 0

@tasks.loop( seconds = 5 )
async def changeStatus():
    status = [f" on { len(client.guilds) } servers", "~help"]
    await client.change_presence(
        activity=discord.Activity(
            type=discord.ActivityType.playing, name=status[tasks.iterationPosition]
        )
    )
    tasks.iterationPosition = (
        0
        if (tasks.iterationPosition is len(status) - 1)
        else (tasks.iterationPosition + 1)
    )

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print( 'bot connected' )
    changeStatus.start()
```

Comment: Can you show us the error that you are getting?

Comment: And narrow down what actually are you trying to achieve?

Comment: i can't because when u programe bot it's like cmd that show erorrs but if there error in code it don't open

Comment: So at least tell what is the expected behavior of your code.

Comment: it should change bot status every 12 sec

Comment: from what to what?

Comment: cycle from ```f' on { len(client.guilds) } servers'``` to ```'~help'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you always assign `0` to `iterationPosition` at the start of loop, instead put it in "global" scope like this:

```py
tasks.iterationPosition = 0

@tasks.loop(seconds=12)
async def changeStatus():
    status = [f" on { len(client.guilds) } servers", "~help"]
    await client.change_presence(
        activity=discord.Activity(
            type=discord.ActivityType.playing, name=status[tasks.iterationPosition]
        )
    )
    tasks.iterationPosition = (
        0
        if (tasks.iterationPosition is len(status) - 1)
        else (tasks.iterationPosition + 1)
    )
```

Comment: i tryed but i have error, you can check my previous question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67429956/discord-bot-not-updating-status

Comment: what error? I can't help you if you just say "I have error"

Comment: and maybe edit your answer so i can see your entire code

Comment: i tryied ur code and it didn't work, i can't send u error bc all error should show at exe console but eexe don't even start that mean that in code is error but i can't say exactly what and where

Comment: i find out how to check code and this is error - 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\ds\bot.py", line 25, in <module>
    tasks.iterationPosition = 0
NameError: name 'tasks' is not defined
[Finished in 0.4s]

Comment: try writing `from discord.ext import tasks` at the top of your script

Comment: but now he send me all messages 3 times lol

Comment: he send messages as many times as on all servers he is

Comment: What messages? You are saying a lot of stuff without context...

Comment: this is discord bot, and when u write to hom commands it should reply, like you write hello he say hi, and now when i write to him hi, instead of hi, he writes me hi hi hi hi separate messages, i checked, number of messages he send depend of servers he work, and this problem is with all commands

Comment: So show me entire code or ask another question because it started to be a seperate topic now.

Comment: Honestly I cannot help you with that, it is working normally when i run it... I think you should try posting another question that describes your problem in detail.